# How is Vuex different than a store object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, store, flux

I'm using Vuex for Vue 2 (kind of like Redux for React). I found an [example](https://skyronic.com/2016/01/03/vuex-basics-tutorial) of usage which updates a counter, with code like this:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(Vuex)

var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    INCREMENT (state) {
      state.counter ++
    }
  }
})

export default store
```

My question is, how is this different than simply forgoing Vuex and making a manual store? Then it would be:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

var store = {
  state: {
    counter: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    INCREMENT (state) {
      state.counter ++
    }
  }
}

export default store
```

Comment: A couple significant differences I've noticed - ability to do rollbacks, integration with the Vue dev tools.

Comment: For a simple use case you don't need vuex and then changing your export to be a constant instead of a var would effectively be the same thing. Vuex just offers a std procedure and traceability. Vuex modules allows for better organisation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It implements other tools, integrations, helpers:

- VueJS Dev Tools integration with roll back, timeline
- Implement third party plugins
- use of mapState, mapActions, map... to simplify coding
- etc,